# iOS Sort array based on float value

Tags: ios, sorting

I wish to sort an array data based on `height` parameter which is in float. I used `NSSortDescriptor` but it isn't working.

Following is my code:

```
NSSortDescriptor *hDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Height" ascending:YES];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[hDescriptor];

[[[appDelegate.arr objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"arrPerson"] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
NSLog(@"%@",[[appDelegate.arr objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"arrPerson"]); // height is printed in random order. not sorted
```

How do I solve this?

**edited: log**

```
(
    {
    Height = "11.5766";
    Name = "abc";
},
    {
    Height = "11.8443";
    Name = "sdfsdf";
},
    {
    Height = "12.211";
    Name = "hnkhjk";
},
    {
    Height = "13.7271";
   Name = "ertert";
},
    {
    Height = "15.2694";
    Name = "sdf";
},
    {
    Height = "21.9242";
    Name = "fgh";
},
    {
    Height = "23.0857";
    Name = "ert";
},
    {
    Height = "6.48365";
    Name = "cvb";
},
    {
    Height = "7.5204";
    Name = "rt";
},
    {
    Height = "8.67856";
    Name = "asd";
}
```

)

Comment: I am seeing that you are not assigning sorted array any where ? `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` will return an array. You will have to do `[[appDelegate.arr objectAtIndex:section] setObject:newArray forKey:@"arrPerson"]` something like this. Make sure it should be mutable dictionary.

Comment: or do `NSArray *newArray = [[[appDelegate.arr objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"arrPerson"] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors]; NSLog(@"%@", newArray);`

Comment: Hey I tried the second option, but it still didn't work. newArray also doesn't contain sorted result. What could be the reason? The key on which I want to sort has float value.

Comment: Paste your array here `[[appDelegate.arr objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"arrPerson"]` paste its log.

Comment: I have pasted the log in my question. Please see the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors:` returns the sorted array. So you are basically just sorting it and discarding the result.

You need to sort and assign this value to the `NSDictionary` you are pulling it out of.

```
NSArray *persons = [[appDelegate.arr objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"arrPerson"];
NSArray *sortedPersons = [persons sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
[[appDelegate.arr objectAtIndex:section] setObject:sortedPersons forKey:@"arrPerson"];
```

But to do that you need to have a `NSMutableDictionary`. If you post more code in your question it might help. But the above is your problem :)

EDIT:
As per discussion in the comments the values are stored as `NSString`s

The following will try to convert any strings as numbers (and any other types):

```
NSArray *sorters = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Height" ascending:YES comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
        NSNumber *n1;
        NSNumber *n2;
        // Either use obj1/2 as numbers or try to convert them to numbers
        if ([obj1 isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
            n1 = obj1;
        } else {
            n1 = @([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", obj1] doubleValue]);
        }
        if ([obj2 isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
            n2 = obj2;
        } else {
            n2 = @([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", obj2] doubleValue]);
        }
        return [n1 compare:n2];
    }]];

NSArray *persons = [[appDelegate.arr objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"arrPerson"];
NSArray *sortedPersons = [persons sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sorters];
[[appDelegate.arr objectAtIndex:section] setObject:sortedPersons forKey:@"arrPerson"];
```

If you can guarantee that the `Height` value will always be an `NSString` or `NSNumber` (and not a `NSNull` if we're dealing with JSON) the following sort descriptor would also work:

```
NSArray *sorters = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Height.doubleValue" ascending:YES]];
```

While the first sort descriptor is a bit longer, its also far more robust in case any other objects are put inside of the `Height` value as then you would get a `class is not key value coding-compliant for the key length` error.

Comment: Tried this, but still the same. The array doesn't get sorted. Please let me know why is it not getting sorted and how do I solve it?

Comment: Are you saying if you log out `sortedPersons`, it is not correct?

Comment: It does sort the values, I don't know what you are seeing. I mocked up a quick example http://ideone.com/jAEUOk#stdin
`2014-04-18 12:34:15.576 prog[22151] Original: ({Height = 1; Name = Tom; }, {Height = 1.1; Name = Dick; }, {Height = 0.9; Name = Harry; })`


`2014-04-18 12:34:15.577 prog[22151] **Sorted**: ({Height = 0.9; Name = Harry; }, {Height = 1; Name = Tom; }, {Height = 1.1; Name = Dick; })`


This works fine!

Comment: You have used NSDictionary. I am using NSArray. Isn't it possible with array?

Comment: You have an array of `NSDictionaries`. The `persons` array I mocked up is exactly the same as yours (just with less values) :)

Comment: I totally don't know what's happening. I tried your dictionary and it worked.--Sorted: (
        {
        Height = "0.9";
        Name = Harry;
    },
        {
        Height = 1;
        Name = Tom;
    },
        {
        Height = "1.1";
        Name = Dick;
    }
) But mine is not at all working. How can this be possible? I debugged a lot but can't reach the bug. Let me know where am I getting wrong.

Comment: Is it possible that float is in double quotes i.e. it is a string so its not working? Is it the reason?

Comment: Also can you please try adding one more field- "RegionCode" = "FR" in all elements of dictionary along with name and height? RegionCode should be in "". Let me know

Comment: What does `NSLog(@"Height class: %@", NSStringFromClass([persons[1][@"Height"] class]))` result in?

Comment: it results in `Height class: __NSCFString`

Comment: I've now changed the example to strings, http://ideone.com/btzXca, it still sorts the array correctly.

Comment: try it out with this: `NSArray *persons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"8.67856", @"Height", @"Tom", @"Name", @"asd", @"RegionCode",nil],
                        [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"19.1515", @"Height", @"Dick", @"Name", @"asdr", @"RegionCode",nil],
                        [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"6.48365", @"Height", @"Harry", @"Name", @"dfg", @"RegionCode",nil],
                        nil];` . It does't work.

Comment: I've updated my answer, try that sort descriptor (there was small typo I just fixed)

Comment: @z22 no problem! Glad we finally got there :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this it may work.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Height"
                                                               ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray = [[[appDelegate.arr objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"arrPerson"]sortedArrayUsingDescriptor:sortDescriptors];
```